# tag in tag empty on .net xml parsing

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, tags, xml-parsing

I'm parsing the xml on my job. I can't change xml creator file untill our other IT group come from holiday. Here is xml file to parse

```
<workhours>
    <name>x</name>
    <workhours>11:00-23:00</workhours>
    <author>y</author>
</workhours>
```

I need get "workhours" inside "workhours" but it's coming empty. I don't know tag in tag is wrong or not but i need to get that data now. Any idea?

by the way, numbering array is not working because my xml file row numbers are could be different for every "workhours"

Comment: I've given an answer, but it would be really helpful if you could show what you're currently trying. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you haven't given any code, so it's hard to know what's wrong... In LINQ to XML this would be easy:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XElement workHours = doc.Element("workhours").Element("workhours");
```

There's nothing inherently wrong with an element of a particular name being nested within another element of the same name.